# Implementing the procducer-consumer pattern with .NET 4.0

Tags: design-patterns, .net-4.0, producer-consumer

With alle the new paralell programming features in .NET 4.0, what would be a a simple and fast way to implement the producer-consumer pattern (where at least one thread is producing/enqueuing task items and another thread executes/dequeues these tasks). Can we benfit from all these new APIs? What is your preferred implementation of this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [IProducerConsuerCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147.aspx) or derive from [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). Samples are provided in the documentation for these items.